# updating user profile on parse with ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have multiple view controllers.

The first is the sign in page with a username and password text field. Where I sign the user up using Parse like this:

```
- (IBAction)signup:(id)sender{
    PFUser *user = [PFUser user];
    user.username = _username.text;
    user.password = _password.text;
    [user signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {

        } else {
            [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            NSLog(@"already username");
            [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            _username.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
            _inuse.text = @"Username is already taken!";
            // Show the errorString somewhere and let the user try again.

        }
    }];
}
```

Then on the next view controllers I want to add information to the user.

So I tried on the next view controller to do this. Where I have two text fields `firstname` and `lastname`:

```
- (IBAction)signup_name:(id)sender{
    PFUser *user = [PFUser user];
    user[@"firstname"] = _firstname.text;
    user[@"lastname"] = _lastname.text;
    [user saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {

        } else {
            [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            NSLog(@"already username");
            [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            _username.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
            _inuse.text = @"Username is already taken!";
            // Show the errorString somewhere and let the user try again.

        }
    }];
}
```

But I am getting the error: 'User cannot be saved unless they are already signed up. Call signUp first.'

I tried adding this to `- (IBAction)signup:(id)sender` When there isn't an `error`:

```
[PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:_username.text password:_password.text
                                            block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
                                                if (user) {
                                                    // Do stuff after successful login.
                                                } else {
                                                    // The login failed. Check error to see why.
                                                }
                                            }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the signup succeeds, the current user is accessible by `[PFUser currentUser]`, so...

```
- (IBAction)signup_name:(id)sender{
    PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
```

Should work.

Comment: does current user come from signup? or do I have to add the log in bit?

Comment: No, I think success on signup gives you a logged in currentUser.  So no extra login.

Comment: Just checked! Yeah signup does log you in!! Thank you very much!